# a fast and optimized database query for scheduling appointments

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mariadb

I'm building a scheduling appointment system. I have a database structure in mind as you see below:

[image]

This is an example for a doctor's working hours:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id | doctor_id | day_number | starts_at | ends_at |
|----------------------------------------------------
| 1  |    1      |     1      | 09:00     | 13:00   |
| 2  |    1      |     1      | 16:00     | 19:00   |
| 3  |    1      |     2      | 09:00     | 13:00   |
| 4  |    1      |     3      | 09:00     | 15:00   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

- as the name suggests, day_number is the number of day in the week. for example, 0 is Sunday.

I'm looking for a fast, efficient SELECT query to get the next free time for scheduling a new appointment according to the doctor's working hours.

- assume each appointment is 15 minutes long.

also if you have any suggestions about the design, Let me know.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: Why is saturday the first (or second, if you count from zero)  day of the week?

Comment: Tip: check spelling of all entity names; you have misspelled `appointment` (2 p’s) as `apointment` (1 p). Changing names is quite difficult post deployment. I worked on a project that had question and answer data, but the original dev (whose 1st language was not English) named the table/columns "anwser". AFAIK it is still named that way, because the benefit of taking the database offline to rename the entities and changing all the SQL was not worth the risk and cost, so everyone just lived with the annoyance.

Comment: @AnnoyinC yeah that's right. I don't know why I made that mistake. the first day of the week is Sunday, which is zero.

Comment: @bohemian I always double-check the spelling just before I use a word in code. I have seen the same problem in projects. thank you for mentioning that.